# Angular Material navbar responsive

Tags: angular, angular-material, navbar, responsive, bootstrap-5

I would like to create a responsive navbar with angular material. I would like to create something this bootstrap navbar:

[see bootstrap responsive navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/casLy.png)

When the screen size is reduced, I would like it to show the Hamburger Menu, as it allows you to do bootstrap.  Which techniques should be applied with Angular Material to obtain a responsive component?

Searching examples on the internet with Angular Material I do not find anything similar.

Comment: You can use a `mat-toolbar` and via media query obtain a responsive design. You also should include what you've achieved so far. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: +1 There is a difference between the bootstrap Navbar Dropdown and the Material flyout hamburger menu. This is a good question

Comment: [Here's a bootstrap navbar](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar/src) with embedded styles, and [here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/app.component.html) how I use it. It's got `<noscript>` support and max-height dropdowns too. But you can just as well only pick the code you need and put it in your application